# Plotting columns of one dataframe dont return curves but something like sticks

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have ".dat" files which were converted into pandas dataframe and results look like this:

```
df95= pd.read_fwf('fes_95-Copy1.dat', header=None, sep=" ")
df95.columns = ['rgyr', 'cmap', 'free','der_Rgyr','der_Cmap']
```

```
          rgyr         cmap     free   der_Rgy  der_Cmap
    0    0.480895   -0.200472   -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
    1    0.481955   -0.200472   -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
    2    0.483016   -0.200472   -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
    3    0.484076   -0.200472   -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
...
35226   1.051359    1.154010    -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
35227   1.052420    1.154010    -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
35228   1.053480    1.154010    -0.0    -0.0    -0.0
```

The column "free" contains "0"s at the beginning and end of the file, but in the middle it can have values up to "-180". In addition, while in the dataframe e.g. the value 8.629338e+01 looks like this, in the original .dat file it is: -86.947612962 (just to make it clear what values are there).
The dataframe looks to be OK, however when I plot column "cmap" vs. column "free" like this:

```
plt.plot(df95["cmap"],df95["free"],label="fes_95")
plt.xlabel("cmap")
plt.ylabel("free energy [kJ/mol]")
plt.legend()
```

It didn't return line/curve as I expected but something which looks like this:

[image]

It should look like this (but with one curve only):

[image]

I try different approaches to plot the data as well, e.g. with df.plot option, convert it to .csv file, etc. I haven't solved why I don't get the nice curve. I assume the dataframe is OK, maybe the problem is in the way how matplotlib handle this dataframe? I can't find source of this "problem", thus I can't solve it. I would like to ask for any suggestions what can be the cause of such behaviour?

edit: here is link to the file [link-to-fes-file](https://vscht-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/cernekoi_vscht_cz/ETU4xw1WZutLtKpxnLXrxxMButydLpn_S1kZrd8GOiXEMA?e=XkvZgB)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Difficult to say without access to the original data. Can you link to the file? Make sure your plotted data don't contain NaN values, though.

Comment: I added link to the original data in my OneDrive

Comment: Im sorry I uploaded wrong document, it should be this fes file: https://vscht-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/cernekoi_vscht_cz/ETU4xw1WZutLtKpxnLXrxxMButydLpn_S1kZrd8GOiXEMA?e=XkvZgB
I am very sorry for the mistake

Comment: The graph reflects your data. They are chunks of changing `free` values for each `cmap` value. You don't see the different `free` values in a line plot due to overlaying lines but  [a scatter plot](https://imgur.com/lrJNZH7) reveals the data points: `plt.scatter(df95["cmap"],df95["free"], marker=".", s=1)`.